# How can I find the multiple of two numbers using Java Modulus

Tags: java

This is the code that I have so far. I just want to know if I'm correct. I am very new to this and most likely I'm correct but I still wanted to know. thanks

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    //variables
    int number1;
    int number2; 
    System.out.println("enter first number: ");
    number1 = input.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("enter first number: ");
    number2 = input.nextInt(); 

    int multiple = number1 % number2;   


    if((number1 % number2) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Yes, " + number1 + " is a multiple of " + number2);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("No, " + number1 + " is not a multiple of " + number2);
    }


    System.out.println("The multiple is: " + multiple);
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, except for the duplicate prompt. This probably belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thank you. I think is also fine, is just that I feel like I'm doing it wrong for some reason.

Comment: The last line doesn't make much sense. I think you mean "remainder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want if a number is divisible by other or not and want to get multiplier if so.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    //variables
    int number1;
    int number2; 
    System.out.println("enter first number: ");
    number1 = input.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("enter second number: ");
    number2 = input.nextInt(); 
    if((number1 % number2) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Yes, " + number1 + " is a multiple of " + number2);
        System.out.println("The multiple is: " + (number1 / number2));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No, " + number1 + " is not a multiple of " + number2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. But if you consider couple of things here it would be good.

Change your second prompt to "enter second number"
Currently you are printing message "The multiple is: " every time whether you find multiple or not.
So print this message only when you found a multiple. Move this line to if block to achieve this.